# how to show a 'looks good' message in jquery validator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I am wondering if something like this is posible

```
.validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },

messages: {
    email: {
            required: "<?php echo get_texto_clave('error_validate_empty'); ?>",
            email: 'Please enter a valid email address',
            whenFieldIsValid: 'looks good'
        }
    }
});
```

To show a message, not error but a confirmation that the input is valid,

how can i do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `validClass` [option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) to write this functionality.  When an input is valid, the plugin will add a specified class to that element.

Insert a hidden div after each of the inputs:

```
<input id="exampleinput" /><div class="correctmessage">Looks Good</div>
```

To hide:

```
.correctmessage{ display: none; }
```

In your validate statement, include the `validClass` option, as well as `onkeyup` and `onclick` if you want the messages to appear as changes are made to the form:

```
.validate({
    validClass: "success",
    onkeyup: true,
    onclick: true
})
```

Then CSS to display the first element of class `correctmessage` after a `success` class (the specificity should override the other CSS block):

```
.success + .correctmessage{ display: block;}
```

`display: inline` is also valid.

Comment: If the form is valid, it gets submitted (or whatever action you want).  When the form is invalid, it automatically adds an error message to invalid inputs.  This allows you to put a success message on all successful inputs.

Comment: If this isn't what you meant, can you rephrase the question?  I added how to make each field validate as you make changes.

Comment: I mean in your exapmle. for what i am seeing. you are not making any difference on the fields. lets say there are 4 fields and you want to validate them separately. maybe you would have 3 'looks good' but 1 'fix field'. if you know what i mean

Comment: This will accomplish that.  First off, the validate plugin is for entire forms.  Second, you simply add the div of class "correctmessage" after *each* element you'd like the message to appear for on correct validation.  It will work for as many elements as you'd like.

Comment: Totaly right. it's just i didn't know about the + selector in CSS and keep thinking that they would be all applied (not separatelly). thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can easily mark each valid field before the form is submitted by slightly modifying the "highlight" and "unhighlight" option:

```
$(form).validate({
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).removeClass("valid").addClass("error");
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).removeClass("error").addClass("valid");
    }
})
```

You can add a hidden element after each input and toggle it's visibility (or display) through css:

```
.valid_message { visibility: hidden; }
.valid + .valid_message { visibility: visible; }
```